# PL/SQL function returns minimal number

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

How to write a simple function that returns minimal salary. IN parameters are salary1,salary2,salary3 (9240, 9750, 8320) and it is forbidden to use finished functions.

I have no code whatsoever. I am very new at this and am trying to learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is not allowed to use existing functions, you can do it using `If then else`

```
create or replace function get_min(s1 number, s2 number, s3 number)
return number
is
  min_sal number := 0;
begin
  ---------------------
  -- if the first value is less than the second value
  -- , then the first value is the min of both values
  -- otherwise the second value is min
  if s1 < s2 then
    min_sal := s1;
  else 
    min_sal := s2;
  end if;

  ------------------------------------
  -- now you check the new min value against the third value.
  if s3 < min_sal then
    min_sal := s3;
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line('min: ' || min_sal);

  return min_sal;
end;
/
```

```
DECLARE 
  v_result NUMBER;
BEGIN

  v_result :=  GET_MIN(1, 1, 1);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(2, 1, 1);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(1, 2, 1);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(1, 1, 2);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(2, 2, 1);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(1, 2, 2);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(1, 2, 3);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(2, 1, 3);
  v_result :=  GET_MIN(3, 2, 1);
END;
/
```

**Result:**

```
dbms_output:
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
min: 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a49ab7dcfef4ad858088cb2cfd4a7e1e)*

Answer (score 1):

The function is already exists in PLSQL. Check it out [here](http://psoug.org/definition/LEAST.htm). There are good examples of how to use it

UPD: As per Pavel mentioned here is a pair of examples

SQL:

```
select least(100, 1, 200) from dual; -- returns 1
```

PLSQL:

```
create or replace procedure get_min(s1 number, s2 number, s3 number)
is
  min_sal number := 0;
begin
  min_sal := least(s1, s2, s3);
  dbms_output.put_line('min: ' || min_sal);
end;
```

Comment: Please, add some examples here. Link only answers considered to be of a very poor quality here on StackOverflow, since the link can get broken and make the answer useless.